# Remapping Keys for the Mac

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have a Windows keyboard I'm using with my Mac (Leopard), and I want to swap some keys (mainly the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Win</kbd> keys). Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [DoubleCommand](http://doublecommand.sourceforge.net/).

> **DoubleCommand** is software for Mac OS X (a kernel extension) that lets
>   you remap keys, in other words change the way your keyboard works.
>   Often used to make a PC keyboard more comfortable with a Mac, swapping
>   the Alt (Option) and Windows (Command or Apple) keys, since they are
>   in swapped positions on Mac and PC keyboards. DoubleCommand is a quick
>   and easy way to fix this if you use a PC keyboard with your Mac.

Comment: It's not a perfect solution. It's extremely limited in what you can remap. It also doesn't work well for laptops because the settings aren't mapped to a particular keyboard, it's global across all keyboards which means you need to go to system preferences every time you go mobile.

Answer (score 8):

System Preference->Keyboard  and mouse.  In the Keyboard tab, you will see a "Modifier Keys" button in the bottom left. This will bring up a dialog that allows you to remap what your Macintosh thinks are the "Control", "Option", "Command" and "Caps Lock" keys.

Comment: this must be a relative new feature. Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/. It's got what you want and much more.