# Remapping of keys in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, keyboard-layout

My MBP comes with a Turkish keyboard but I'm using US layout. However, the key just under ESC gives § instead of ` (back-quote) which I frequently use.

I need to remap this key but I couldn't find any information except remapping of modifier keys. How can I do it?

Comment: As a side point, on my keyboard (UK) the backtick is between the left shift and Z keys

Comment: Another side note, that symbol is there in all layouts I've seen.

Comment: normally it is just under ESC key in windows and linux pcs. at least that is more accesable for us that deal with linux, latex, lisp. And finally it is used for switching application windows in Mac OS X.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/18212/remapping-keys-for-the-mac

Comment: thank you Nippysaurus but doublecommand takes care of only modifier keys. backquote is not covered by it. i've tried both and found keyremap4macbook more powerful

Comment: Off-topic, but can anyone tell me: why the heck even have such a stupid layout as the default? Who uses `§` and `±` on a regular basis? And why have such a small shift key, or a tiny `ctrl`, and why is the `﹨` where the bottom of the where the point of the `⮐` key should be? Yes, *should* be. I understand why you want to have a `£` or `€` instead of `$` above the four, but everything else is absurd. The amount more I have to pay to import a US layout in Eastern Europe is absurd, at least in Germany I can get US-International no problem... and no, Latvians and Estonians don't want this either.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try [KeyRemap4MacBook](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). It seems to offer a lot of options. Maybe it will fix your problem as well. Here's what it says about it:

> This is a very powerful keyboard
>   remapper for Mac OS X.  In addition to
>   simple key remapping, it has special
>   remapping modes like Emacs-mode,
>   SandS-mode (Space and Shift).

Comment: Perfect solution Alex. Did a find on § on KeyRemap4MacBook's UI and found the feature of Remapping Paragraph(§) to Backquote (`). Thank you

Comment: It's odd how I couldn't find this application after searching so much

Comment: I searched for **macbook** key remapping. Maybe you just checked for **mac** key remapping :).

If this worked for you, please consider marking it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Oh, by the way, glad it worked for you :)

Comment: Love it! Found my exact case! It means I am not the only one with this weird mapping problem - Apple should listen to users...

Comment: Exellent app, except it seems to reinterpret key codes in real time instead of remapping them through some kind of system properties which causes key repeat rate to drop significantly - deal braker for me, I use arrow keys in text editors a lot.

Comment: For those wondering the Paragraph(§) key is called `non_us_backslash` in Karabiner at the moment (in case you were also searching haha endlessly)

Answer (score 40):

You can use the [hidutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2450/_index.html) command-line tool, which comes with macOS since Sierra 10.12:

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[{"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingSrc":0x700000064,"HIDKeyboardModifierMappingDst":0x700000035}]}'
```

The keys are referenced by Usage ID from the USB HID Usage Tables Specification. The section key <kbd>§</kbd> is listed as "Keyboard Non-US \ and |" (0x64, see https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8133633) and backtick <kbd>`</kbd> is "Keyboard Grave Accent and Tilde" (0x35).

Comment: Should be the accepted answer. Thank you so much. Buying keyboards with "proper" US layouts when you are a programmer living overseas is a total pain in the butt. Thankfully at least Ubuntu is interpreting this `§` as grave natively.

Comment: please keep in mind that if you have a configurable external keyboard this mapping can do the reverse on it

Comment: Also, if you want to swop the keys (and not just replace § with \`), then you'll need to add the reverse mapping to that JSON array as well.

Comment: This is not persisted across system restarts. You have to run it every time the system restarts.

Comment: Works in Monterey 12.6.6

Answer (score 8):

Mac 10.12 sierra users should use this: https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements

DMG download: https://pqrs.org/latest/karabiner-elements-latest.dmg

In "From key", I selected the option with Japanese characters and in To key I selected `` GRAVE_ACCENT_AND_TILDE (`) ``.

[image]

Comment: Instead of the Japanese characters, I'm using non_us_backslash. You can view the exact character you need to map from `Karabiner-EventViewer` app.

Comment: Yes! I cannot believe that so few people are having this problem. This worked great for me--just a small issue I have is that now when I type "˜" I get small tilde initially instead of the one I want (~) for that to happen I still need to press space. Any ideas how to get rid of that?

Comment: Karabiner Elements is the way to go for Mac users everywhere.

Comment: except for the Karabinier Elements being marked as untrusted app by Mac OS X. 
As well the fact that Karabiner Elements is enabled as an Accessibility service and basically has access to everything you type. I have been using it for some time, but seriously considering to find a safer solution after I started experiencing strange issues with my Mac OS X Catalina.

Comment: Does anyone know any alternatives to Karabiner Elements? I keep getting "key is ignored until pressed again" for my fixes.

Comment: Karabiner Elements did not work for me. It is VERY difficult to use and VERY complex and only for advanced users.
Worse yet, after uninstalling Karabiner Elements, THEY KEY I WAS REMAPPING NO LONGER WORKS AT ALL!