# How do I convert Caps Lock into Delete on the Mac?

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, capslock

FYI: None of the answers to this question fixed the problem so don't bother reading any further.

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remapping of keys in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/37042/remapping-of-keys-in-mac-os-x)

This way I could avoid using Fn+BackSpace. That would be really convenient.

Comment: I suppose people who closed this didn't really read this post. If I follow the suggestion of the duplicate I only need to pull the source code of the program, find the new mapping codings, recompile the program and then it's good to use. Basically this question was not answer by the post above. Conclusion is nobody has an easy way to achieve this - (and maybe that this forum doesn't work as well as stackoverflow :( )

Answer (score 1):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to forward-delete on a Mac.

(P.S. Macs have a <kbd>Delete</kbd> key, not a <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key. ;) )

Comment: Actually, the ctrl+d shortcut is nice to know. Thanks. It would however still be convenient to use Caps Lock key for something useful. :)

Comment: @rui, swap caps lock with ctrl. Mac and Linux have an option in Keyboard Preferences, but in Windows you have to hack the registry

Comment: Would be really handy to have the Linux like Delete key there instead. Plus Control + d doesn't seem to work in some applications... :(