# How can I remap right ALT to right CMD in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard, remapping

I use the Polish keyboard layout in OS X Leopard.

I'd like to remap right <kbd>alt</kbd> to right <kbd>cmd</kbd> and disable right <kbd>alt</kbd>.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remapping of keys in Mac OS X](http://superuser.com/questions/37042/remapping-of-keys-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: @soandos I'm not sure the solution there works, are you?

Comment: @slhck, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @soandos Because there's no option in KeyRemap4MacBook to change right ⌘ to any possible key – only several predefined ones IIRC.

Comment: I don't have a mac, nor access to one. I really have no idea, just the questions seemed the same to me

Answer (score 3):

KeyRemap4MacBook does have a predefined setting for changing the right command to option:

[image]

If you also want to disable the right option, you could use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::COMMAND_R, KeyCode::OPTION_R</autogen>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::OPTION_R, KeyCode::VK_NONE</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: KeyRemap4MacBook is now known as [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en).