# Is it possible to remap keycombinations on macos?

Tags: macos

i am new to MacOS and i'm customizing my preferences right now. As i was trying to use the usual linux shortcuts i realized that they are a little bit mixed up. Is it is possible to remap the cmd-left-arrow shortcut which is moving the cursor to the next word to option-left-arrow which is moving the cursor to the front of the line.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remapping of keys in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/37042/remapping-of-keys-in-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

There are several options. E.g. [Karabiner](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org/) works perfectly for me.
You can also have a look at this question: [Remapping of keys in Mac OS X](https://superuser.com/questions/37042/remapping-of-keys-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).